# How can I know in a diynamic way what functions will be called

Tags: php, reflection

I have the class bellow:

```
class Foo
{
    function a()
    {
         $this->b();
    }

    function b()
    {
    }
}
```

How can i dynamically knows what functions `a()` is calling??

There's a way to know that `a()` will call `b()`?

Comment: Could you elaborate about your real purpose and constraints ?

Comment: Sorry, but it will take a lot of time. I made this sample as simple as possible.

Comment: But is about reflection in PHP

Comment: As far as I can see, `$foo->b()` will cause **stack overflow** error... so, I cant understand, what exactly are you trying to do...

Comment: I'm so sorry guys, that was my fault. I updated the code.

Comment: I'm only asking because Reflection itself will get you a good level of insight about a lot of things but won't get you the actual code of any method. But maybe we might suggest other ways if we understand better what you want to achieve.

Comment: All right, i'll update the code with a full sample.

Comment: I don't think that's possible other than looking at the OpCode (you might get the Vulcan extension and `exec()` it). There's also [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) which is kind of the opposite: if you put it in `b()`, you can see which function called it.